# Table with most frequent combinations with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The dataset

```
ID Product
1   A
1   B
2   A 
3   A
3   C 
3   D 
4   A
4   B
5   A
5   C
5   D
.....
```

The goal is to have the most frequent combinaisons of product by ID regardless the number of string value.

The expected result here is :

```
[A, C, D]  2
[A, B]     2
[A, C]     2
......
```

Like that but with a working value

```
import itertools

(df.groupby('ID').Product.agg(lambda x: list(set(itertools.combinations(x,**?**))))
                 .explode().str.join('-').value_counts())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ID, aggregate to [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#frozenset) and count the occurrences with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.groupby('ID')['Product'].agg(frozenset).value_counts()
```

output:

```
(B, A)       2
(D, C, A)    2
(A)          1
Name: Product, dtype: int64
```

Alternative using sorted tuples:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Product'].agg(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()
```

output:

```
(A, B)       2
(A, C, D)    2
(A,)         1
Name: Product, dtype: int64
```

Or strings:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Product'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x))).value_counts()
```

output:

```
A,B      2
A,C,D    2
A        1
Name: Product, dtype: int64
```